# How can I get the second value in multi-value parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

Is it possible to return the second, third and fourth values in a multi-value parameter?  I can get the first one to populate just fine by using the parameter itself, but if I want to show the second one it doesn't work.

I've tried to use `=Choose(2,CChar(Join(Parameters!EventIDs.Value,",")))` or some variation of that, but to no avail.  Is there some other way to do this?  My parameter is ordered the way I want it so I just need to get the second value in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), you should be able to access the values and labels by index (in your case, index `1` would give you the second value, since arrays are 0-based):

```
' First
Parameters!EventIDs.Value(0)
Parameters!EventIDs.Label(0)

' Second
Parameters!EventIDs.Value(1)
Parameters!EventIDs.Label(1)

' And so on
```